# Constant: No component factory found for error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I'm having a constant error with my Angular application.

Error:

```
NbWindowComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: No component factory found for ViewProductModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

Project Layout:

[Project Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55o14.png)

I am trying to import the view-product-modal component so I can show it from my products component. I've imported it into the products.module.ts and I'm still getting this error.

Products.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Ng2SmartTableModule} from 'ng2-smart-table';

import {ThemeModule} from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import {ProductsComponent} from './products.component';
import {ViewProductModalComponent} from "./view-product-modal/view-product-modal.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ThemeModule,
    Ng2SmartTableModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProductsComponent,
    ViewProductModalComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ViewProductModalComponent
  ]
  entryComponents: [
    ViewProductModalComponent
  ],
})
export class ProductsModule {

}
```

View-product-modal.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'view-product-modal',
  template: `
    <p>
      view-product-modal works!
    </p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./view-product-modal.component.scss']
})
export class ViewProductModalComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I'm very confused. I've done with other components and they've worked fine. I'm not sure why it's working this time.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
exports: [
   ViewProductModalComponent
],
entryComponents: [
   ViewProductModalComponent
]
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mg8jtc)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've updated my products.module.ts file with the updates (See above) However, I appear to be getting the same error.

Comment: Have you restart app ?

Comment: Try to put export before entryComponent. As in my answer. I have update  it.

Comment: Hi, I have added exports before entry components and updated the above. However, I am still getting this same error. Very confusing.

Comment: Put comma , after export array.

Comment: Hi, this is why I'm confused. Do you need any more information maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your module:

```
exports: [
    ViewProductModalComponent
],
entryComponents: [
   ViewProductModalComponent
]
```

It's called entry components, I recommend you to read the angular doc: https://angular.io/guide/entry-components